# C# can't take CPU,GPU,RAM,HDD InstallDate (f.e Win32_Processor, Win32_VideoController, Win32_PhysicalMemory, Win32_DiskDrive)

Tags: c#, datetime, gpu, cpu

I can't get DateTime from InstallDate - CPU, GPU, RAM, HDD. Always appears an error System.NullReferenceException, or datetime like 01.01.0001 00.00.00

This is my code with 2 expample:

```
DateTime CpuDateTime, GpuDateTime;   and etc.

    ManagementObjectSearcher mos =
new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
{
CpuDateTime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo["InstallDate"].ToString());
}

    ManagementObjectSearcher video =
new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController");
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in video.Get())
{
GpuDateTime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo["InstallDate"].ToString()); 
}

CpuTimeLabel.Text = CpuDateTime.ToString();
GpuTimeLabel.Text = GpuDateTime.ToString();
```

if i use this code : ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo["InstallDate"].ToString()); i take this error  -  System.NullReferenceException

if i use this code without .ToString: ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo["InstallDate"]); I take like this 01.01.0001 00.00.00

Please Help. Thank you very much

Comment: Missing property values in WMI queries are entirely normal.  For this one it is even documented, "This property does not require a value to indicate that the object is installed".  Do play first with [WMI Code Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: The default DataTime when constructed is 1/1/1 which is what you are getting.

Comment: jdweng I know. but how can i take NOT default DateTime? i can't ))